# Unable getting string from WebService customer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need to read string from my customer server.

the string that i need to call is:

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8082/My_ws?applic=MyProgram&Param1=493&param2=55329
```

The result I get is a string.

If I run it in the browser I get an answer string - OK

i need to get it in my HTML & javascript program

i try this:

```
function Look() {
   $.ajax({
     ServiceCallID: 1,
     url: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8082/My_ws?applic=MyProgram&Param1=493&param2=55329',
     type: 'POST',
     data: '{"Param1": "' + 2222 + '"}',
     data: '{"Param2": "' + 3333 + '"}',
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     dataType: 'json',
     success:
           function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                ALL = (data.d).toString();
                  },
    error:
           function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     alert(textStatus);
                  }
                });
            }
```

Comment: 1 - You have 2 `data` properties in request, 2 - in browser you make `GET` request, and in code - `POST`, 3 - what is ServiceCallID? 4 - do you see errors in console?

Comment: You could start by putting a console.log(data) in your success function. What do you see on the console?

Comment: Yes Ilya is right about those two things, you are making a GET not a POST request here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to use stringify if the data is Json otherwise remove JSON.stringify, you cannot have 2 data parameters either, your using utf-8 presume that is a MS web srvc, if your sending data up it's post (usually).

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'Post',
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   url: "//localhost:38093/api/Acc/",  //method Name 
   data: JSON.stringify({ someVar: 'someValue', someOtherVar: 'someOtherValue'}),
   dataType: 'json',
   success: someFunction(data), // pass data to function 
   error: function (msg) {
    alert(msg.responsetext);
  }
```

});